# How to generate download URL for Azure container in Python

Tags: python-3.x, containers, azure-blob-storage

I have a container named "test" in Azure Storage. I want to generate a URL for this. File directory inside it looks like below:

```
test
    -> annotate # This is a dir
        -> file1.txt
        -> file2.txt
    -> images # This is a dir
        -> file1.jpg
        -> file2.jpg
```

I want to generate URL so that when it is accessed I can download the complete container `test` including all the files and directories inside it. Now I have done this before but in that approach I was only downloading the blob using below code:

```
account_name = "deeusblobstorage"
container_name = "rperodct"
blob_name = "face_1_7285.jpg"
account_key = "hMlIRXCjAomfDRfied8Y5FPwTVnWEkEDuVsw//CQtkiOdcFD/y5wUcxH9Ou7Ni+DtDQFwe23YbZ3Qia9gw=="
url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key,
    container_name=container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

url_with_sas = f"{url}?{sas_token}"
print(url_with_sas)
```

In the above code I was specifically mentioning the blob inside the container to download, which then generates url. But how can we generate url for a container so that all the files and directories inside it can also be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can we generate url for a container so that all the files and
> directories inside it can also be downloaded.

Simply put, you cannot directly download all blobs in a container just by using a container URL. What you would need to do is first list the blobs inside the container and then download individual blobs.

In order to list the blobs in a container and then download each blob, you would need to generate a SAS token on the container using [`generate_container_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-generate-container-sas) method. You would need both `read` and `list` permissions in your SAS token.

Once you have the SAS token, you would first list the blobs and then create SAS URL for each blob using the blob URL and SAS token you obtained for the container.

Comment: Okay, so that means I will have two different URLs because I have two directories in the container. Is that correct?

Comment: No. Directories are virtual in blob storage. You would still need to list the blobs in the directories and download individual blobs. To summarize - you can only download individual blob using Blob Storage API and would write custom code when you need to download multiple blobs.

Comment: I understand that directories are virtual in blob storage. In fact, I have a working code which downloads each blob individually. Its just that this whole code will go inside an API call, so I need to return a URL using through which client can download the data in his browser instead of downloading it on api server. I am still not  clear how can I have 1 single URL for all the blobs, but anyways I am still checking. Thanks

Comment: `I am still not clear how can I have 1 single URL for all the blobs, but anyways I am still checking` - Sorry if I was not being clear. You cannot have 1 single URL for all the blobs. Each blob will have their own download URL.